# Filtering a "dictionary" in bash

Tags: bash, dictionary, glob

I'm trying to filter and  iterate a dictionary with globing expressions.

I've tried in bash 4:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A dict
dict["key-foo"]="foo-value"
dict["key-bar"]="bar-value"

for key in "${!dict[*-foo]}"; do
  echo "${key}"
done
```

but the key is empty.

Comment: There might be built-in prefix matching support, but there certainly isn't general-purpose globbing; you'll need to do the match yourself inside the loop.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy in that case I better group my key-values in separate arrays. Thanks

Comment: Yup, that's what you'll want to do. Even in a language with very efficient dicts (Clojure comes to mind), you can take a prefix-based subset but not a suffix-based one, since a prefix can be used to select a subtree whereas evaluating a suffix requires a full traversal and is thus O(n) (so all you get by having the language do it for you is a lower constant factor).

Comment: @MatiasBarrios, re: your presently-deleted answer, consider editing that to `while IFS= read -r -d '' key; do echo 'Key %q has value %q' "$key" "${dict[$key]}"; done < <(printf '%s\0' "${!dict[@]}" | grep -z 'foo$')`. Requires GNU grep, but doesn't have bugs if your keys have spaces or newlines. Has a substantial startup cost for the pipelines and external `grep` process, but if it's a sufficiently huge dict, that may be amortized away to favor `grep`'s better performance.

Answer (score 1):

As Charles mentioned in his comment, your best bet is to iterate over all keys and select matching keys to take into process.

```
for key in "${!dict[@]}"; do
    case $key in
    ( *-foo )
        : # do something with the key
    esac
done
```

Comment: Missing a `;;`, no?

Comment: Since we're already requiring one bashisms (associative arrays), could also `[[ $key = *-foo ]] || continue` just as tersely.

Comment: @Benjamin no, ;; is not required for the last case

Comment: Interesting, the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-case) makes it look non-optional.

Comment: @Benjamin POSIX says it's optional